# Holomorphic versus harmonic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Is it true that any holomorphic function on domain $D$ is of the form $u_x-iu_y$ for some harmonic function $u$?
Motivation for this question is the problem of existence of harmonic conjugates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to rephrase everything in terms of forms. Given a holomorphic function $f$, rewrite it as $u-iv$, where $u$ and $v$ are real. Suppose you had a function $w$ ($u$ in your original question) with $w_x = u$, $w_y = v$. Then $w$ is automatically harmonic by the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Now, the existence of such a $w$ is exactly the same statement as that $udx+vdy$ is an exact 1-form - it's automatically closed by the Cauchy-Riemann equations again.

So this is now a question of simple connectedness. If your domain is simply connected, every closed form is exact, as desired. If it's *not*, I can find some closed form that's not exact (because for domains in the plane, $\pi_1 \neq 0$ means that the de Rham cohomology $H^1(D;\Bbb R) \neq 0$). Now a harmonic 1-form is one such that $d\omega = d*\omega = 0$, where $*$ is the Hodge star; to phrase that in terms of $\omega = udx+vdy$, we say precisely the Cauchy-Riemann equations for $u-iv$: $v_y - u_x = 0$ (the condition that $d\omega = 0$) and $v_x + u_y = 0$ (the condition that $d*\omega = 0$).

Now, *lastly*, what we need to know is that every cohomology class has a harmonic representative. I have not checked this carefully, but I believe this still follows from Hodge theory and the elliptic operator theory; what you lose when you don't assume compactness is uniqueness of harmonic representative. So the answer to your question is "Yes, when $\Omega$ is simply connected; and no, when $\Omega$ is not."

Comment: I agree that $f-u+iv$ is holomorphic iff $u,v$ satisfy Cauchy-Riemann (I assume $f$ to be $C^2$). I also agree that given holomorphic function $f=u+iv$ both $u$ and $v$ are harmonic. The pair $(u,v)$ consists from harmonic conjugates iff $u+iv$ is holomorphic is by definition. However I don't see why any holomorphic function is of the form $u_x-iu_y$ for some harmonic $u$.

Comment: @truebaran: I completely misread your question! My apologies. I've completely rewritten the answer.

Comment: Ok, many thanks for your answer!

Comment: @truebaran: I want to warn that I am not confident about the claim that every form has a harmonic representative. 80% sure, but not 100%. It would take more care than I'm willing to put in to be sure.